# Create new column for number of times that string appears

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to create a new column with the number of time a string appears in another column.

Example:
The new column would count the number of times "X" appears in the caption column.

```
col1    caption                 new_column
a       "hello X, welcome!"      1 
b       "Beautiful day"          0
c       "X or x. Box."           1
d       "Xina is a cool name. X" 2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do:

```
df['res'] = df['caption'].str.count('X')
print(df)
```

**Output**

```
  col1                 caption  res
0    a       hello X, welcome!    1
1    b           Beautiful day    0
2    c            X or x. Box.    1
3    d  Xina is a cool name. X    2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use base string methods to Object type columns (which is the case here), so we can use `count` method here to count substring in each cell of `caption`

```python
In [2]: df = pd.DataFrame({"col1": list("abcd"),
   ...:               "caption" : ["hello X, welcome!", "Beautiful day", "X or x. Box.", "Xina 
   ...: is a cool name. X"
   ...: ]})

In [3]: df['new_column'] = df.caption.str.count("X")
   ...: df
Out[3]: 
  col1                 caption  new_column
0    a       hello X, welcome!           1
1    b           Beautiful day           0
2    c            X or x. Box.           1
3    d  Xina is a cool name. X           2
```